# Power BI: On-premise gateway issues while using Excel file and database as data sources

Tags: powerbi, gateway, powerbi-datasource, onpremises-gateway

this is probably something simple that I am overlooking, but here's what I have going on:

I've built a dashboard that sources a few tables from my database. The report is also using an Excel file (which is stored on my local machine and our OnePoint Drive) for a couple other tables.
We've set up the on-premise gateway so that the published reports can access the tables from the database. Through the Manage Gateways page, it shows online:
[Gateway - Online Status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTT4o.png)

Opening the report still shows errors and says there is no gateway connection. See here: [No gateway connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P97nY.png)

When I go to the dataset settings, it seems that the Excel file is what is causing the issue: [Gateway setting issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZVpO.png)

Does anyone know what I need to do to fix this? How do I make a connection to the Excel file that is on OneDrive and detach it from the gateway cluster that has been set up?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using a local file path. If it is in OneDrive, open the query and change the source to point directly at the cloud version. There are instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/sharepoint-onedrive-files

Comment: I've tried it both ways. The issue seems to be with how the gateway was setup or maybe how it's connecting. I tested by building a new report within Power BI online and visuals using tables sourced from the Excel file work. However, if I build a visual based off tables sourced from the SQL database, I get error messages. 
I've opened a ticket with Power BI support so hopefully they can help me out.